# how can i make fluid or water inside bottle unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, simulation, fluid

how can i make fluid or water inside bottle like in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGEbtLCf7tU

**Edit:** I have tried hard, but unable to start it anyway, what i find from google is

Search Result :

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/54982/is-it-possible-to-make-liquid-water-in-unity3d.html

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/fluvio-fluid-dynamics-for-unity.95255/

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/475028/how-do-you-put-liquid-in-a-bottle.html

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1237815/how-do-you-simulate-a-liquid-inside-a-bottle-using.html

But didn't get any help from these searches.
Plugins are available on the asset store but i want to make my own physics of water simulation inside the bottle.

Any good technique of making water like in the tutorial??

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Google is your friend, typing "fluid simulation Unity" will lead to many results. The StackOverflow community is not here to do the research job for you.

Comment: I know this but i am asking for technique of making water inside unity.I tried making from particles but didn't get my desired results.